# Is there a way to have moveable, protected elements in powerpoint?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Let's say I have a powerpoint with a circle, and a square. The circle has an animation attached to it, which is triggered by the clicking on the square.

Can I flatten the circle, so no-one can move it/click on it, whilst keeping the animation?

I've tried the flat pack add in, with no success. I can't find any code that does it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction/tell me I'm wasting my time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, that's not possible. You can lock objects, but then the animation will not be able to run. VBA is unable to change the XML to lock or unlock objects.

Here's more info about object locking: [OOXML Hacking: Locking Graphics](http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2016/09/xml-hacking-locking-graphics/)